# How to use devtool in node NW?

Tags: node.js, devtools, nw.js

Devtool, toolbar and other features was removed from nw 0.13.*. 
How can I to use the devtool in current versions?

I created a nw project who uses nw 0.12.1. I decided to upgrade it to current version, and then, the desired tools was absents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are docs about [devtools in nw](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/v0.13.0-beta7/For%20Users/Debugging%20with%20DevTools/)

> open DevTools programmatically using NW.js API win.showDevTools()

Or...

> Remote Debugging
>
> You can use the --remote-debugging-port=port command line option to specify which port the DevTools should listen to. For example, by running nw --remote-debugging-port=9222, you can open http://localhost:9222/ in your browser to visit the debugger remotely.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  require('nw.gui').Window.get().showDevTools();
</script>
```

That will work in all versions of NW.js.

Answer (score 0):

In nwjs 69.0.3497.100, you can just press `F12`